# Windows python script to run a server and continue

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, popen

I am working on my python script to launch a server, may be in background or in a different process and then further do some processing before killing the launched server.

Once the rest of the processing is over, then kill the launched server.

For Example

```
server_cmd = 'launch_server.exe -source '+ inputfile
print server_cmd
cmd_pid = subprocess.Popen(server_cmd).pid
...
...
... #Continue doing some processing
cmd_pid.terminate() # Once the processing is done, terminate the server
```

Some how the script does not continue after launching the server as the server may be running in infinite loop listening for a request. Is there a good way to send this process in background so that it doesn't expect for command line input.

I am using Python 2.7.8

Comment: can you include your full code.

Answer (score 2):

It's odd that your script does not continue after launching the server command. In `subprocess` module, `Popen` starts another child process while the parent process (your script) should move on.

However in your code there's already a bug: `cmd_pid` is an `int` object and does not have `terminate` method. You should use `subprocess.Popen` object to call `terminate` method.

Answer (score 2):

Making a small change resolved the problem

server_proc = subprocess.Popen(server_cmd, **stdout=subprocess.PIPE**)

server_proc.terminate()

Thanks Xu for correction in terminate.